# Converting Quick BASIC to VB.Net - Random Access Files

Tags: vb.net, file, random-access, qbasic

I'm trying to convert an old Quick BASIC program to VB.Net. There doesn't appear to be any direct replacement for the old file statements. Building a database seems like overkill for my simple needs.

How can I do the following in VB.Net?

```
OPEN "test.dat" FOR RANDOM AS #1 LEN = 20
FIELD #1, 10 AS a$, 10 AS b$
LSET a$ = "One"
LSET b$ = "Two"
PUT #1, 1
GET #1, 1
PRINT a$, b$
CLOSE #1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileopen.aspx), [FilePut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileput.aspx), and [FileGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileget.aspx) statements should be pretty direct replacements for most of your code above.

```
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileOpen(1, "test.dat", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Shared)

    Dim output As New Fields

    output.A = "One"
    output.B = "Two"

    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FilePut(1, output, 1)

    Dim input As New Fields

    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileGet(1, input, 1)

    Debug.WriteLine("A = " & input.A & "; B = " & input.B)

    FileClose(1)
```

Comment: FIELD #1, 10 AS a$, 10 AS b$

How do you replace the FIELD statement in this example?