# Reading (with Filesystem.FileGet) VB6 record file (written with Put) with C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I need to read data from a legacy database file produced by Visual Basic 6.
From the legacy software I found that file was written using `Put` and passing sort of records as parameters to the `Put` function. These structures are defined as follows:

```vb
Type THE_TYPE
    FIELD_1 As Single
    FIELD_2 As String * 20
    FIELD_3(1 To 50) As Single
    FIELD_4(1 To 10) As String * 1
End Type
```

My Types are larger and more complex but I've put in `THE_TYPE` the different definitions I have in my project. I've found that importing `Microsoft.VisualBasic` gives me access to VB functions similar to those used to write the file, so I'm opening and closing the file with `FileSystem.OpenFile()` and `.CloseFile();` now I need to finally read data contained and since the original function was:

```vb
Public RecordContent As THE_TYPE
[...] 
Get #1, recordNumber, RecordContent
```

I suppose I can use something similar, like `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet()`.
So the question is, how do I define a container, I suppose a class, similar to the original VB6 Type `THE_TYPE`? How do I call `.FileGet()` to correctly fill this object?

Comment: While GSerg may have pointed you in the right direction, know that there are big differences in the way `Put` works between the `Open` modes of `Random` and `Binary`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266212(v=VS.60).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266177(v=vs.60).aspx for details. I bring this up because if the `String` and array members are all of fixed size, I wondered if the VB6 app used the `Open ... Binary` mode.

Comment: +1 For importing `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and using `FileSystem`. You'd be amazed [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290976/vb6-how-are-binary-files-encoded-using-put-statement) [often](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886096/converting-quick-basic-to-vb-net-random-access-files) people overlook those!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is defining attributes properly on the structure declaration in VB.NET. Provided the structure will always be initialized by `FileGet`, you don't need to manually initialize its fixed fields in a constructor, otherwise, you do.

```vb
Structure THE_TYPE
    Public FIELD_1 As Single
    <VBFixedString(20), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=20)> Public FIELD_2 As String
    <VBFixedArray(49)> Public FIELD_3 As Single()
    <VBFixedArray(9)> Public FIELD_4 As Char()
End Structure
```

Obviously, the arrays will have to start from zero, so the upper bounds are shifted down.

Reading from the file:

```vb
Dim d As System.ValueType = New THE_TYPE()

FileOpen(1, "...", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default, 234)
FileGet(1, d, 1)
FileClose(1)
```

`234` is the size of the structure in VB6. It's bigger in VB.NET, so you want to hardcode that.

Comment: +1. I have not tested this, and hardcoding 234 might be safest, but would `Marshal.Sizeof` return the correct structure size?

Comment: @MarkJ No, in this case it returns same as `Len`, which is 244. This is probably because `Char` is two bytes in .net.

Comment: TYVM!!
In C#: `System.ValueType data = new UserDataStruct();`
Than: `FileSystem.FileGet(fileId, ref data);`
Will solve '**Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from** 'ref A' to 'ref System.ValueType''

Comment: @GSerg Your solution has worked for me, but in my converted project, I found a more complex data structure. `VB6 code: Channels(1 To 2, 1 To 10, 1 To 2) As String * 1` do you know how I can represent this in vb6 for it to work with the FileGet? i Tried :<VBFixedArray(1)> Dim Channels(,,) As Char : 'Object of type 'System.Char[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Char[,,]'.'

Comment: @Decoder94 `VBFixedArray` supports up to two dimensions. Try declaring the array as dynamically sized so that `Put` writes the [array descriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/put-statement#remarks) too which can be read by `Get`.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg I have no control over how the file is written, can I get around this without needing to modify put?(my software only reads no writing)

Comment: @Decoder94 Try `VBFixedArray(40)> Dim Channels() As Char`.

Comment: That works, I have to change the way I access the data in the structure but that's fine. but how did you come up with the number 40? is there a formula?

Comment: @Decoder94 You have 40 elements in the array (2 * 10 * 2), 1 char each. That's 40 chars.

Comment: @GSerg I have this:Elements(1 To 2, 1 To 22, 1 To 2) As Integer in my vb6 structure and in VB.Net I have converted to <VBFixedArray(88)> Dim Elements() As Short, these are integers does the formula you gave work for this instance? because integers can have 3 digits on so on, whereas chars is one character?

Comment: @Decoder94 An `Integer` is two bytes. Textual representation of these two bytes ("[42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)", "[2A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)", "[XLII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)") does not matter. You have correctly matched the number of elements (2 * 22 * 2 = 88) and the size of the element (`Integer` = `Short`), the rest should not concern you.